# Sufficiency and MLE of $\theta$ where $f(x;\theta)=\dfrac{1}{2}e^{|x-\theta|},-\infty<\theta<\infty$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

> Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a random sample from the density.
> $f(x;\theta)=\dfrac{1}{2}e^{|x-\theta|},-\infty<\theta<\infty$.

**Discuss the sufficiency and MlE of $\theta$ for this density**

I can write this density function as

$ f(x;\theta) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-(x-\theta)} ,  \theta < x < \infty \\
      \dfrac{1}{2}e^{(x-\theta)}  ,  -\infty < x < \theta \end{cases}$

I am skipping the whole proof as I am preparing for time based exam. I just want to know
for the first part,we have $\theta<x_{(1)}$ and for second part  $\theta>x_{(n)}$

So $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(n)}$ are jointly sufficient. Am I right ?
and for MLE   $\theta$ satisfies $ x_{(n)}<\theta<x_{(1)}$ which seems absurd. Mle doesnt exist in this case?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/240496/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1678740/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thaks and do check my last question posted. Shed some knowledge there please that might be helpful for me

Comment: @StubbornAtom What about the sufficiency of it?

Comment: $(X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)})$ and $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ are both sufficient for $\theta$ when $f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x-\theta|}$.

Comment: $(X_{(1)},....,X_{(n)})$ all the ordered statistics or just $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$?

Comment: All of them....

Comment: @StubbornAtom How? Could you please prove it in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find MLE for $\theta$ an easy approach is the usual one

$$L(\theta)\propto e^{-\Sigma_i |X_i-\theta|}$$

$$l(\theta)=-\Sigma_i |X_i-\theta|$$

To be maximized...

Maximizing $-\Sigma_i |X_i-\theta|$ is the same as minimizing

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\Sigma_i |X_i-\theta|
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

It is well known that $\hat{\theta}$ which minimize (1) is the sample median

(the proof is easy and I can show it to you if necessary)

Comment: MLE I understood.Please tell me about the sufficiency of this density.

Comment: Tommik help me please ?

Comment: @Daman:  as already said, order statistics are sufficient estimator for $\theta$. There is the same exercise on Casella Berger, Chapter 6, Exercise 6.9. Here you can find all the solutions http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams570/Solutions-Casella-Berger.pdf

Comment: Thanks  alot tommik

Comment: Tommik I don't wanna post this is as a new question since it's a small one can you check if it's TRUE or FALSE. It's false I think they haven't subtracted intersection. I have an exam so that's why I am asking informally please help me.[Here](https://prnt.sc/ym4h9c)

Comment: @Daman : it's TRUE. The requested probability is $P(X<4)=1-e^{-4}$. If you want you can do as  you think but the result is the same: $P(X<3)+P(2<X<4)-P(2<X<3)=1-e^{-3}+e^{-2}-e^{-4}-(e^{-2}-e^{-3})=1-e^{-4}$

Comment: Thanks actually I computed $F(0)$ as $1$ thats why I got wrong answer but $F(0)=0$